# XML/XSLT Stacked class conditional tree

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm fairly new to XSLT (and not extensively experienced with XML), and I'm having a hard trim wrapping my head around the problem.

I have a class that consist of a ValidationResultType (which is in one of three states), a message, and a List of N children of the same class. This is then serialized to XML, in order to product the following XML :

```
<ChildErrors>
    <ErrorCarrier>
        <Message>Sheet 'So and so' had 3 warning(s)</Message>
        <ChildErrors>
            <ErrorCarrier>
                <Message>Row 1 had 1 warning(s)</Message>
                <ChildErrors>
                    <ErrorCarrier>
                        <ChildErrors>
                            <ErrorCarrier>
                                <Message>Some warning</Message>
                                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                            </ErrorCarrier>
                        </ChildErrors>
                        <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                    </ErrorCarrier>
                </ChildErrors>
                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
            </ErrorCarrier>
            <ErrorCarrier>
                <Message>Row 3 had 1 warning(s)</Message>
                <ChildErrors>
                    <ErrorCarrier>
                        <ChildErrors>
                            <ErrorCarrier>
                                <Message>Some warning</Message>
                                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                            </ErrorCarrier>
                        </ChildErrors>
                        <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                    </ErrorCarrier>
                </ChildErrors>
                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
            </ErrorCarrier>
            <ErrorCarrier>
                <Message>Row 6 had 1 warning(s)</Message>
                <ChildErrors>
                    <ErrorCarrier>
                        <ChildErrors>
                            <ErrorCarrier>
                                <Message>Some Warning'</Message>
                                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                            </ErrorCarrier>
                        </ChildErrors>
                        <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
                    </ErrorCarrier>
                </ChildErrors>
                <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
            </ErrorCarrier>
        </ChildErrors>
        <ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType>
    </ErrorCarrier>
</ChildErrors>
<ValidationResultType>Warning</ValidationResultType></ErrorCarrier>
```

What I want is a tree view with these errors, and a conditional formatting on the ValidationResultType. If its a Failure, then its red, if its a warning, then blue, if a success then nothing.

The XSLT I have thus far is :

```
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Message</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ErrorCarrier/ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier">
<tr>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ErrorCarrier/ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier/ValidationResultType='Success'">
      <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="Message"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Message"/></td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It's not working in the way I want it to, and all my attempts at googling has not yielded any helpful results thus far. Can anyone perhaps help me in the right direction?

Comment: change `<xsl:when test="ErrorCarrier/ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier/ValidationResultType='Success'">` to `<xsl:when test="ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier/ValidationResultType='Success'">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `<xsl:for-each>`, the node you loop over becomes the context node.

This means that your current code is looking for a node that doesn't exist. (`ErrorCarrier/ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier/ErrorCarrier/ChildErrors/ErrorCarrier/ValidationResultType`)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer (which I should have seen!) explains my bigger problem.